# $uibModal: get instance from method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I'm using modals via method, like:

```
this.showModal = function () {
  return $uibModal.open({...});
}
```

and then in some method i call this function:

```
this.showModal().result.then(function (someResult) {...});
```

but how can i use dismiss, using method call?

becouse i use it without method, i can close my modal so:

```
$uibModal.open({...}).result.then(function (someResult) {
  this.$dismiss();
})
```

but i have no clue, how to use dismiss, when i use methods promise...

maybe somebody have an idea?

Comment: `$dismiss()` is available on modal scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open method returns a modal instance with `open, closed,dismiss ,close,rendered ,returned` method.

In  your case it is `this.showModal` is modal instance.

SO, you can call the close the method like this.

```
var self = this;
self.showModal = function () {
  return $uibModal.open({...});
}
//close the modal
self.showModal.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the modal in an object, either in the scope or move this to a service, and then call dismiss on the modal object

```
var modalInstance;

this.showModal = function () {
  modalInstance = $uibModal.open({...});
  return modalInstance;
}
```

and when using the promise

```
this.showModal().result.then(function (someResult) {
    modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
});
```

Comment: dismiss is only available on `$uibModalInstance `

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN "The open method returns a modal instance, an object with the following properties:...dismiss(reason) (Type: function) - Can be used to dismiss a modal, passing a reason." https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal/docs

Comment: @MarcusH got it Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is making a modal instance :

```
$scope.doSomething = function(){
     var modalOptions = {...};
     openModal(modalOptions);
}

function openModal(modalOptions) {
            $scope.myModalInstance = $uibModal.open(modalOptions);
            $scope.myModalInstance.result.then(function () {
                //success callback
            }, function () {
                //error callback;
            });
        }
```

Later if i want to call close or dismiss simply call `$scope.myModalInstance.close()`  and `$scope.myModalInstance.dismiss('cancel')`.